# php preg_match exclude negative number

Tags: php, preg-match

```
preg_match_all('/(\b[0-9]+)/',"This is -44 55433 example",$amatches);
```

This will grab all numbers, however how would I exclude anything with a minus in front of it like -44.

Thanks

Comment: it includes minus : `(-?\b[0-9]+)`

Comment: I did google first and could not find anything that excludes negative number that is why I asked.  The answer above includes a negative number not excludes.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: @user3757731 Do you still need an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this solution will help you

```
preg_match_all(
    '/(?:^|[^\-\d])(\d+)/' ,
    'This is -44 55433 example',
    $matches
);

var_dump($matches[1]);
```

Comment: Ok Casimir, check '/(?:^|[^\-\d])(\d+)/'

Comment: Edited answer checked. `<°ççççççç>`